# When can zmq_msg_send return -1 and EAGAIN without a ZMQ_DONTWAIT flag?

Tags: zeromq

Using ZeroMQ 4.0.5, I've got some code that serves as a broker, reading from one socket and writing to another. The target socket of the send is a TCP DEALER. In a particular complex test case, zmq_msg_send errors and sets errno to EAGAIN.

As I read the doc, this should not be possible; EAGAIN should require the ZMQ_DONTWAIT flag or a timeout. I don't pass ZMQ_DONTWAIT, and I have not called zmq_setsockopt to set a timeout. What am I missing?

I added a socket monitor, and the evidence suggests that when this happens, there is no one on the other end to receive. So, according to the doc, I'd expect to block, since I haven't passed ZMQ_DONTWAIT and I haven't set a timeout.

```
int len = zmq_msg_recv(&msg, fromSocket, 0);
if (len == -1) {
    int err = errno;
    if (err != ETERM) {
        fail("ZmqTransportMultiplexer::pass %s %s from zmq_msg_recv\n", trace,
             zmq_strerror(err));
        // no need to log ordinary closure.

    }
    throw ZmqMultiplexerShutdown();

}

/* Preserve the part structure. The code in ZmqTransport.cpp would
 * work just the same if this converted to multiple messages and
 * did not preserve the multi-part structure, but this code
 * accounts for the possibility that we change our mind.
 */
int more = zmq_msg_more(&msg);
len = zmq_msg_send(&msg, toSocket, more != 0 ? ZMQ_SNDMORE : 0);
if (len == -1) {
    int err = errno;
    if (err != ETERM) {
        fail("ZmqTransportMultiplexer::pass %s %s from zmq_msg_send length %d\n",
             trace,
             zmq_strerror(err),
             zmq_msg_size(&msg));
    }
    throw ZmqMultiplexerShutdown();
}
```

Comment: did you set send timeout on the toSocket? eagain can happen from send timeout as well.

Comment: No I did not set a timeout.

Comment: what is he error number you get and what is the message?

Comment: As I wrote, the error number is EAGAIN and of course the message is the standard message for EAGAIN.

Comment: can you show the number inside the errno and the message that is printed to the screen?

Comment: if you don't believe that I'm capable of debugging at this level, then I'm afraid that I am someone that you cannot help. I am not interested in proving to you that I understand how to inspect an errno value.